# How to combine async await with Bluebird cancelable promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, bluebird

I have an async operation that should be cancelable. So I decided to use Bluebird Promises to get it done.
However, when I try to run it, my code never completes, because (in case of the promise being canceled) everything gets stuck at "await".

Do you have any elegant solution for this problem?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bluebird-playground-forked-dfbp61?welcome=true

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");

Promise.config({ cancellation: true });

let myP = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
    // In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code that runs 2 seconds


    onCancel(() => {
      console.log("onCancel called");
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("before resolve");
      resolve("Success!"); // Yay! Everything went well!
    }, 2500);
  });

const run = async () => {
  console.log("Start");

  const prm = myP();
  setTimeout(() => {
    prm.cancel();
  }, 1000);

  await prm;
  console.log("After await prm"); // <- this code is never executed, what can I do?
};

run()
  .then(() => console.log("Finished")) // <- "then" is never called, what can I do?
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Using bluebird to make a promise cancelelble might be overkill, and there is a standard way to do it using AbortController.

Comment: @Keith what is the overkill in using bluebird? In terms of performance or code complexity or something else? I find it pretty straight forward...

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using Bluebird, it's a good lib, but installing it just to get the cancel feature would be overkill, especially when it's built into the browser already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 has this already built in `AbortController`, it's maybe not obvious it can be used for other things, not just for fetch.

Below is your example using the `AbortController`.

Please note, when you abort, it's your responsibility to either `reject` or `resolve` to keep code flowing.  In most cases I usually reject, and if required catch this error as normal.

ps. I also updated to make abort cancel the timeOut too, as for some reason you missed that bit out in your example.

```js
let myP = (sig) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const tm = setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("before resolve");
      resolve("Success!"); // Yay! Everything went well!
    }, 2500);
    //sig.onabort = () => {
    sig.addEventListener('abort', () => {    
      console.log('aborted');
      clearTimeout(tm);
      resolve();
    });
  });

const run = async () => {
  console.log("Start");

  const sig = new AbortController();
  const prm = myP(sig.signal);  
  setTimeout(() => sig.abort(), 1000);

  await prm;
  console.log("After await prm"); 
};

run()
  .then(() => console.log("Finished")) 
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

ps. It's also possible to use 1 signal to cancel multiple promises, in this case it's usually better to use `addEventListener('abort', e)` instead of `sig.onabort = e`

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `reject()` in the onCancel callback and catch the exception by wrapping the `await prm` with try catch block or just let it throw:

```js
const Promise = require("bluebird");

Promise.config({ cancellation: true });

let myP = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
    onCancel(() => {
      console.log("onCancel called");
      reject();
    });
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Success!"), 2500);
  });

const run = async () => {
  console.log("Start");
  const prm = myP();
  setTimeout(() => prm.cancel(), 1000);
  await prm;
};

run()
  .then(() => console.log("Finished"))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

---

And Keith is right in the comment. You can use a `AbortController`.

```js
const controller = new AbortController();

let myP = (sig) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (sig?.aborted) return reject()
    let timer
    timer = setTimeout(() => resolve("Success!"), 2500);
    function handleAbort() {
      clearTimeout(timer)
      signal?.removeEventListener("abort", handleAbort)
      reject()
    }
    signal?.addEventListener("abort", handleAbort);
  });

const run = async () => {
  console.log("Start");
  const prm = myP(controller.signal);
  setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 1000);
  await prm;
};

run()
  .then(() => console.log("Finished"))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Your example does not work. "After await prm" is never logged.

Comment: @stoefln will `await prm` throws an error? if it does, wrap it with try catch block.

Comment: Just try it yourself. It doesn't work.